# Why do erroneous results occur when using the break function with a 'for loop' in a Python list which has the same values at different position?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

Here is my python list and for loop with break.

```
x = [1, 4, 8, 3, 4, 9]
for a in x:
    if a == x[4]:
        break
    print(a, end="")
```

When I break and print 5th position, it should be print as follows;

```
1483
```

but it gives the output as follows;

```
1
```

can anyone explain this issue?

Comment: `4 == 4` (`a[1]` and `a[4]`) so the loop breaks on the second iteration

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code:

```
x = [1, 4, 8, 3, 4, 9]
for a in x:
    if a == x[4]:
        break
    print(a, end="")
```

Here when you run this it prints `1`.
This happens because when the loop runs the first time its condition is something like this: `if 1==4`, which returns False, so it is continued and prints `1`

And the second time the loop runs the condition is like this: `if 4==4`, which returns True, so the loop breaks without running the print statement and you get an output of `1`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But when it's false, the loop should continue,  isn't it? why its get breaks? can you please elaborate more on this answer?